# Mongoose query through the element inside the array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `mongoose` model:

```
let schema = new Schema({

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    confirmed: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    payload: [{
        type: {
           token: blablabla,
           type: blablabla
        }
    }]

});
```

And i want find user by `payload.token`. How can I do that? I tried `$elemMatch`, but it does not work.

Comment: What's `blablabla`?

Comment: Just some variable

Comment: i did mistake: payload should be array of objects

Comment: Is that how it's exactly defined in your models?

Comment: Can you please update your question with `payload` as an array of objects, if it is so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
.find({'payload.type.token': token})
```

Answer (score 0):

If `payload` is an array of objects and you want to find users by token value , below query should work :

```
db.users.find({payload: {$elemMatch: {'type.token':'blablabla'}}});
```